# Table pagination in Android Phonegap

Tags: cordova, dynamic, pagination

I tried lot of code but nothing help me. How to do pagination in dynamic table content in Phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

Load the dynamic data into table first, then apply JavaScript, and goal

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/Xugej/)

```
$('td', 'table').each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(i+1);
});



$('table.paginated').each(function() {
    var currentPage = 0;
    var numPerPage = 10;
    var $table = $(this);
    $table.bind('repaginate', function() {
        $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
    });
    $table.trigger('repaginate');
    var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
    var $pager = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
    for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
        $('<span class="page-number"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
            newPage: page
        }, function(event) {
            currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
            $table.trigger('repaginate');
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
    }
    $pager.insertBefore($table).find('span.page-number:first').addClass('active');
});
```

Look in the fiddle for full example.

Comment: @AtanuCSE: you are welcome to answer whatever you like here, but I've cast a "too broad" close vote on the question - we like to encourage posters to show what they have tried, to avoid the situation where posters no longer have to make an effort on their own.